# Problema con la dimensión de un vector de string en C++

Tags: c++, array, string

No tengo mucha experiencia programando en C++, pero estoy obligado a usarlo para un trabajo. Estoy usando los vectores de C++ por primera vez, y estoy teniendo muchos problemas con las dimensiones. Quiero crear un vector de string que solamente contenga 3 posiciones, el problema es que, al insertar elementos en el vector, me termina quedando de 6 posiciones.

```
int main(){

vector<string> vecString = vector<string>(3); //Se supone que esto hace que el tamaño maximo de mi vector sea de 3

cout<<vecString.size()<<endl; //Tamaño del vector antes de insertar valores

vecString.insert(vecString.begin(),"Area");
vecString.insert(vecString.begin()+1,"Perimetro");
vecString.insert(vecString.begin()+2,"Volumen");

cout<<vecString.size()<<endl; //Tamaño del vector despues de insertar valores

for (int i = 0; i < vecString.size(); i++)
{
    cout<<vecString[i]<<endl;
} }
```

La salida por pantalla de esto es un 3 primero, luego un 6, y después me tira "Area" "Perimetro" "Volumen" seguidos de 3 cadenas vacías.

¿Hay alguna forma de que el vector cuente con un tamaño fijo desde el inicio y que se mantenga igual? Es decir, que el tamaño nunca cambie, sino que cambie el contenido del vector.

Answer (score 4):

Tu primera asunción es falsa:

```
vector<string> vecString = vector<string>(3);
```

Esta línea crea un vector con 3 elementos. El valor de cada elemento será el que aplique el constructor por defecto de `std:string`, que en este caso es una cadena vacía. Así, cuando haces:

```
cout<<vecString.size()<<endl;
```

Obtienes 3, que es **el número de elementos que tiene el vector**.

Después insertas 3 elementos más:

```
vecString.insert(vecString.begin(),"Area");
vecString.insert(vecString.begin()+1,"Perimetro");
vecString.insert(vecString.begin()+2,"Volumen");
```

Con lo que el vector tendrá, finalmente 6 elementos.

**Solución**

**No hay forma** de limitar el tamaño de un vector. La STL te ofrece un contenedor de tamaño fijo que es `std::array`:

```
std::array<3, string> vecString;
vecString[0] = "Area";
vecString[1] = "Perimetro";
vecString[2] = "Volumen";
vecString.insert(/* ... */); // ERROR: no existe este metodo
```

Si quieres / tienes que usar `std::vector`, no podrás limitar de forma nativa el tamaño del mismo... es algo que tendrás que programar tu.

En cuanto a rellenar el vector, puedes usar `push_back`:

```
vector<string> vecString; //Creamos el vector

vecString.push_back("Area");
vecString.push_back("Perimetro");
vecString.push_back("Volumen");

std::cout << vecString.size();
```

O, si ya sabes los valores por defecto del vector (y, como supongo compilas con C++11 o superior), también puedes usar listas de inicialización (esto también funcionará con `std::array`):

```
vector<string> vecString = { "Area", "Perimetro", "Volumen" };
```

Answer (score 0):

Sucede que en traducciones entre el español y el ingles la palabra *vector* estuvo siendo usada para definir la palabra *array*, siendo que el contenedor vector tiene la característica de aumentar su tamaño dinámicamente, a diferencia de los arrays que se debe definir su tamaño al inicializarse.

Sin embargo si aún deseas utilizar el vector que ya definiste, debes **asignar valores** en el vector ya creado en lugar de **insertarlos**.

Para esto existe una función dentro de "vector" es `fill_n`

este sería un código de ejemplo que hace lo que quieres.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

vector<string> vecString = vector<string>(3); //Se supone que esto hace que el tamaño maximo de mi vector sea de 3

cout<<vecString.size()<<endl; //Tamaño del vector antes de insertar valores
/*
vecString.insert(vecString.begin(),"Area");
vecString.insert(vecString.begin()+1,"Perimetro");
vecString.insert(vecString.begin()+2,"Volumen");
*/
// llena en la posición inicial, 1 elemento, con el valor "Area"
fill_n(vecString.begin(), 1, "Area"); 
fill_n(vecString.begin()+1, 1, "Perimetro"); 
fill_n(vecString.begin()+2, 1, "Volumen");  

cout<<vecString.size()<<endl; //Tamaño del vector despues de insertar valores

for (int i = 0; i < vecString.size(); i++)
{
    cout<<vecString[i]<<endl;
} }
```

Comment: ¿No sería mejor usar los corchetes en vez de `fill_n`? No se, es como matar moscas a cañonazos

Comment: SI, es posible usar los corchetes empezando en 0, luego en 1 y luego en 2, sin embargo si se quiere usar `vecString.begin()` no es posible usar los corchetes... si, parece matar moscas con cañonazos, pero es muy similar a lo que el OP estaba haciendo, así que solo cambie su lanzallamas que no servia por un cañon que si le funciona